# b2World behaves weirdly (BOX2d + COCOS2d)

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, box2d

im making game with `cocos2d + box2d`.game works fine, but after some time of play my b2world goes hanged (ground line getting disappeared in drawDebug mode) and some of my b2bodies' attributes become `NAN`.(i dont know what code should i paste here ! :( )

is this code problematic??

```
std::vector<b2Body *>toDestroy;    
    //Iterate over the bodies in the physics world
    for (b2Body* b = world->GetBodyList(); b; b = b->GetNext())
    {                    
        if (b->GetUserData() != NULL) {
            //Synchronize the AtlasSprites position and rotation with the corresponding body
            CCSprite *myActor = (CCSprite*)b->GetUserData();

            myActor.position = CGPointMake( b->GetPosition().x * PTM_RATIO, b->GetPosition().y * PTM_RATIO);
        myActor.rotation = -1 * CC_RADIANS_TO_DEGREES(b->GetAngle());


            if(myActor && myActor.tag==5){

                if([myActor opacity]==0){                     

                    toDestroy.push_back(b);                        

                }
            }   
    }   
}
```

Comment: start with the world update code, collission callbacks and how you create & delete bodies.

Comment: thanks buddy...i had debugged my all lines ..and i found that there was a expression wich tends to divide by zero exception in my calculation which was stucking whole world ...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

i had debugged my all lines ..and i found that there was a expression wich tends to divide by zero exception in my calculation which was stucking whole world ...

Comment: @IronMan84 He **is** the author and he is stating what was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

In init event Create World properly like below

**b2Vec2 gravity = b2Vec2(0.0f, -9.8f);
        _world = new b2World(gravity);**

Comment: i have already..

    b2Vec2 gravity;
    gravity.Set(0.0f, -10.0f);    
    bool doSleep = true;    
    world = new b2World(gravity,doSleep);   
    world->SetContinuousPhysics(true);